# GitLab - VCPKG error when downloading all the needed libs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, vcpkg

I have created this [repository](https://github.com/Vildnex/example_gitlab_and_vcpkg) where I recreated this bug and explained every step individually. Could any of you explain to me what exactly I am missing or is this a bug on the VCPKG side?

The short description is that when I am running the VCPKG command `./vcpkg install --feature-flags=manifests` which is going to be used inside of the Dockerfile is going to fail to one of the libs that have to be downloaded, each time will fail to other libs, is not going to be the same every single time.

How can I fix this? Does anyone know?